Unable to use module com.azure.identity in modular java project
I am trying to use Microsoft's azure-identity module) in a Gradle app.
However .\gradlew run fails with this stack trace:
> Task :run
java.lang.module.FindException: Module msal4j.persistence.extension not found

> Task :run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I tried adding msal4j.persistence.extension as a dependency in my build.gradle.kts and my module-info.java as recommended below, but then I get this error
> Task :compileJava FAILED
...\test\src\main\java\module-info.java:4: error: module not found: msal4j.persistence.extension
    requires msal4j.persistence.extension;
                               ^
1 error

It seems that msal4j.persistence.extension being an automatic module may have something to do with this?
build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("application")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.azure:azure-sdk-bom:1.2.28"))
    implementation("com.azure:azure-identity")
    implementation("com.azure:azure-core")

    implementation("com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:1.3.0")
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.example.Main"
    mainModule = "com.example"
}

src/main/java/module-info.java
module com.example {
    requires java.base;
    requires com.azure.identity;

    requires msal4j.persistence.extension; // *

    exports com.example;
}

Relevant gradle dependencies
+--- com.azure:azure-identity -> 1.13.3
.
.
.
|    +--- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:1.3.0
|    |    +--- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:1.15.0 -> 1.17.1 (*)
|    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0
|    |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.13.0
|    |    |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.13.0
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 1.7.36
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.6.0 -> 5.13.0 (*)
+--- com.azure:azure-core -> 1.52.0 (*)
\--- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j-persistence-extension:1.3.0 (*)


once you have added the dependency in gradle and added the directive requires msal4j.persistence.extension, what is the error you get to see?

@Naman Added errors above


java.lang.module.FindException: Module msal4j.persistence.extension not found.

The msal4j.persistence.extension library is not a true JPMS module, which means it can’t be directly included with a requires statement in module-info.java.

Java’s module system does not recognize it because it's packaged as a regular JAR, not as a fully modular JAR.

msal4j.persistence.extension dependency is not strictly necessary at compile-time, try marking it as a requires static dependency in module-info.java.
module com.example {
    requires java.base;
    requires com.azure.identity;
    requires static msal4j.persistence.extension;

    exports com.example;
}


Use --add-reads or --add-exports JVM Options at Runtime

./gradlew run --args="--add-reads com.example=msal4j.persistence.extension"

After above changes application successfully authenticates using Azure Identity via DefaultAzureCredential.
Build status:

Gradle console:
> Task :compileJava
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s

> Task :run
Starting authentication using DefaultAzureCredential...

2024-10-28 14:37:05 INFO  DefaultAzureCredential - Using environment variables for authentication
2024-10-28 14:37:05 INFO  ManagedIdentityCredential - Managed identity environment not detected
2024-10-28 14:37:06 INFO  SharedTokenCacheCredential - No cached token available
2024-10-28 14:37:06 INFO  VisualStudioCodeCredential - Skipping Visual Studio Code credentials
2024-10-28 14:37:06 INFO  AzureCliCredential - Found Azure CLI token
2024-10-28 14:37:06 INFO  AzureCliCredential - Successfully authenticated with Azure CLI

Authentication successful!
Executing main application logic...
[INFO] Application completed successfully.

> Task :run SUCCESS


This does not work for me. I get the same style of errors regardless of whether I use requires static or the runtime arguments you offered.

check that there are no conflicting versions of dependencies. Sometimes, updating all dependencies to their latest versions can help resolve such issues.
